# Distro recommendation for "Out The Box Multi Touch Tablet Support"

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, tablet, touch-screen

I have a Dell Inspiron Duo - The tablet netbook, the 1090. It's beautiful, and I want to get the most out of it.

I don't mind digging deep into a distro and installing patches and such to get multitouch working, but that's me. I have to think of others that also would like this goodness.

So my question, which distro has the best multi touch / tablet support out the box.

> Imagine I have to recommend something
>   to someone about to go on an Arctic
>   expedition, who has a touch screen laptop, and needs FOSS installed because of cutbacks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What distributions work out of the box with tablet computers?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2849/what-distributions-work-out-of-the-box-with-tablet-computers)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend Ubuntu as it tends to have the latest software and drivers. The latest version (11.04) supports multitouch out of the box (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/GettingStarted/Natty), but whether that includes the 1090 will depend on what multitouch device it has (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/HardwareSupport).

Answer (score 1):

I have a Planar 23 inch 2430mw display. It works flawlessly on touch with Windows 7 and 8. The only Linux Distribution which I have found which works out of the box is Ubuntu 11.10. I have tried Debian, Fedora , Suse and nothing I have found will even detect my display USB interface. I tried playing with Ubuntu 12.04 and  tried everything I could find on the net to add touch nothing worked. I screwed up X so badly I had to re-install Ubuntu.

I believe with the release for Win8 in the next few months (4Q12) we will see a flood of Tablets, Slates, Laptops and Monitors all with touch. I sure home some Linux Guru with the necessary skills will develop a method to get this huge number on Win 8 devices to work on touch with all Linux Distro's.